# Count line lengths in file using powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

If I have a long file with lots of lines of varying lengths, how can I count the occurrences of each line length?

Example:

> this
>   is
>   a
>   sample
>   file
>   with
>   several
>   lines
>   of
>   varying
>   length

Output:

```
Length Occurences
1      1
2      2
4      3
5      1
6      2
7      2
```

Have you got any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For high-volume work, use `Get-Content` with `-ReadCount`

```
$ht = @{}
 Get-Content <file> -ReadCount 1000 |
 foreach {
  foreach ($line in $_)
   {$ht[$line.length]++}
}

$ht.GetEnumerator() | sort Name
```

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
get-content <file> | Group-Object -Property Length | sort -Property Name
```

Depending on how long your file is, you may want to do something more efficient